# Using Istanbul to find code coverage with manual testing

Tags: angularjs, code-coverage, babeljs, parceljs

Using step mentioned on link https://vijayt.com/post/code-coverage-of-manual-testing-using-istanbul/
to find code coverage in `instanbul` with manual testing but  my current application in angular version 1 using parcel bundler.

When I add `.bablerc` with plugin `intanbul` it stopped application with error :

> Application 'currentApp' died in status NOT_MOUNTED: